# Container views in IOS

Tags: ios

I wanted to use a Container View to initiate another view controller, but I can't see to find any information on how to alloc it programmly. I can do it from the user interface, but if I want to create one with the coes, and link it up to a UIviewController, how can I do that? Does it behave like a normal UIview?

Comment: `- [UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]` & co. Read Apple's excellent documentation.

Comment: but I would like to use the container

Comment: Set it up as a child view controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I follow your question, you're asking how to use view controller containment in code. I'd suggest checking out [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) section of the *View Controller Programming Guide,* which shows you code for doing this, including adding a child view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
[self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

When using child view controllers (at least ones that don't take up the whole screen), it's useful to have a `UIView` on the parent view controller's view, that dictates the boundaries of the child view controller. It greatly simplifies a bunch of tasks. In the above code snippet, they're assuming that the subview is called `frameForContentController`.

Or removing one (in this code snippet, `content` is the `UIViewController *` that references the child controller being removed):

```
[content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
[content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
[content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
```

And if you want to replace a child controller with another child controller:

```
- (void) cycleFromViewController: (UIViewController*) oldC
                toViewController: (UIViewController*) newC
{
    [oldC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];                        // 1
    [self addChildViewController:newC];

    newC.view.frame = [self newViewStartFrame];                       // 2
    CGRect endFrame = [self oldViewEndFrame];

    [self transitionFromViewController: oldC toViewController: newC   // 3
          duration: 0.25 options:0
          animations:^{
             newC.view.frame = oldC.view.frame;                       // 4
             oldC.view.frame = endFrame;
           }
           completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [oldC removeFromParentViewController];                   // 5
             [newC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            }];
}
```

I'd also suggest checking out [WWDC 2011 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal UIView which is owned by a parent VC. Create a child VC and add it to the parent VC with the help of `addChildViewController:`, then add child VC's view to container view as a subview - `addSubview:` in VC's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Make sure do to a `didMoveToParentViewController` whenever you do `addChildViewController`.